# How to assign a value of base page element from child page's Page_Load?

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance

I'm probably not the first who has this problem, but I can't find such question and solution for it.

I have a base .aspx page and child page which inherits from the base page.
From child's `Page_Load` method I call a method on a base page like `base.SetLiteral(value)` which acceses a literal defined in the base page. I get a NullReferenceException, as the literal is null.

It probably has to do with page lifecycle as base page's controls are not instansiated at that point yet.

How can I do it?

EDIT

Here is a stack trace of the exception. Doesn't say anything to me.

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source=PageInheritance
StackTrace:
   at PageInheritance.BasePage.SetLiteral(String value) in D:\crap-projects\PageInheritance\BasePage.aspx.cs:line 17
   at PageInheritance.Page1.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\crap-projects\PageInheritance\Page1.aspx.cs:line 13
   at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
InnerException:
```

Comment: Can you post the top few lines of the stack trace? Is `base` null? or is the nullreferenceexception being thrown from inside the SetLiteral method?

Comment: Do you have to do it Page_Load? If you do it PreRender, all controls should be initialized.

Comment: @Connell Watkins `base` is not null, the exception is thrown inside `SetLiteral` method when I do `MyLiteral.Text = value`

Comment: `MyLiteral` probably isn't initialized yet. Look at @Connell Watkins' answer for information on the page life cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it looks like when one inherits an .aspx page it's only the code behind which is being inherited. The markup ( .aspx itself) is not inherited and there is no way (like ContentPlaceHolder in a Master page) to define what elements (from derived, base page or both) one wants to be on the result page.

As base .aspx page is not inherited no controls added to it in designer ever initialized. I don't really understand how it works though (Page_Init is called but how page decides not to initialize its controls is a mistery) Can anyone explain this bit?

I will probably have to use Master page to achieve my goal, but I will continue my research and update my question.

If I'm mistaken somewhere please let me know.

EDIT

Yes, I achieved what I needed to do using Master page instead of .aspx page inheritance. Did not have any problems there.

P.S.

I did find a way to inherit an .aspx page having markup in base page here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/page_templates.aspx but it looks like complete hackery to me.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, this will happen when the base pages control's are not initialised.

Take a look at [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview - Life-Cycle Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#lifecycle_events) if you haven't already. As you can see, it **should** work in the `Page_Load` and I don't really see what the problem is. Try moving the event to an event later on in the page life-cycle, such as the [LoadComplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.loadcomplete.aspx) event.

Comment: Tried to do it from child's PreRender and LoadComplete , doesn't help, the same problem

Comment: If a Control hasn't loaded by the LoadComplete method, something else is going wrong. `Find all references` on the `MyLiteral` control and wap a breakpoint on the line that sets the variable. See the call stack when the breakpoint is hit.

Comment: I edited the question and added the stack trace, I doesn't help me, may be will say something to you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this can apply to your problem but you could create a class and have both pages inherit from same class, which in turn will inherit from basic `System.Web.UI.Page`.
You can place the shared method in the new class and it will be accessible from both pages.

Comment: I have a few pages which inherit from the base page. The method is accessible allright, it's base page's controls are not instansiated yet when I call them.

Answer (score 0):

Something doesn't seem right there, but if that is the case you could try creating an event handler on the base page that fires once the controls are initialized:

In the base page:

```
public event EventHandler BasePageInitialized;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.BasePageInitialized != null)
        this.BasePageInitialized(this, e);
}
```

In the child page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        base.BasePageInitialized += new EventHandler(Base_Initialized);
}

protected void Base_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    base.SetLiteral(value)
}
```

Comment: Tried that, `Base_Initialized` is never called. Moreover if I try to add the handler in child's `Page_Load` base's `Page_Load` is never called. If I add the handler in child's `Page_LoadComplete`, base's `Page_Load` is called, but `Base_Initialized` is not called anyway.